# SP13: Adding Shading to Custom List

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, css

I have a custom list created in SharePoint 2013.  I have few lines of css in a script editor.  When I add Shading style under modify view the css added stops working.  To add the shading without using modify view I created more css.  But, the css for the shading is not working.  Can anyone see what I am missing?

CSS code for Shading

```
 <style type="text/css">
.ms-alternatingstrong 
{
background-color: #F2F1EC;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the default style and change .ms-alternating instead. If you prefer

```
.ms-listviewtable {
    width: 100%;
}
```

makes it look exactly like shaded view with the added bonus of having the search box.